# JS function is not called inside a form

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am new to JS. can u find me the problem and suggest thereby?? Js client side validation is not called. I have server side validation too. by clicking the button only the server side validation is being called. can u guys help?

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"              CodeBehind="Users.aspx.cs" Inherits="JSApp.Users" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>JsApp</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ValidatingForm() {
            var b = true;
            if (document.getElementById("FnTextBox").valueOf == "") {
                document.getElementById("Label4").innerText = "beshi Required";
                b = false;

            } else {
                document.getElementById("Label4").innerText = "";
            }
            if (document.getElementById("LnTextBox").valueOf == "") {
                document.getElementById("Label5").innerText = "koravabe required";
                b = false;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("Label5").innerText = "";
            }
            if (document.getElementById("EmailTextBox").valueOf == "") {
                document.getElementById("Label6").innerText = "ajeeb vabe required";
                b = false;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("Label6").innerText = "";
            }
            return b;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="FN"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="FnTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="LN"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="LnTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="EmailTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="sendButton" runat="server" OnClick="sendButton_Click" OnClientClick="return ValidatingForm()" Text="Send" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

aspx.cs:server side

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace JSApp
{
    public partial class Users : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ValidateForm())
            {
                SaveData();
            }
        }

        private void SaveData()
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SampleConnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection connection=new SqlConnection(cs);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spInsertUsers",connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter fnParameter=new SqlParameter("@fn",FnTextBox.Text);
            SqlParameter lnParameter=new SqlParameter("@ln",LnTextBox.Text);
            SqlParameter emailParameter=new SqlParameter("@email",EmailTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(fnParameter);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(lnParameter);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(emailParameter);
            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();


        }

        private bool ValidateForm()
        {
            bool b = true;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FnTextBox.Text))
            {
                b = false;
                Label4.Text = "Required";
            }
            else
            {
                Label4.Text = string.Empty;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LnTextBox.Text))
            {
                b = false;
                Label5.Text = "Required";
            }
            else
            {
                Label5.Text = "";
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailTextBox.Text))
            {
                b = false;
                Label6.Text = "Required";
            }
            else
            {
                Label6.Text = "";
            }
            return b;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try a submit component, and use the onsubmit event. It might work better.

Comment: Sanity check 1 - view the rendered html and see if your `id` for the elements match what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

innerscript attribute does not have cross browser compatibility. using textContent had solved the issue. when i use innerscript it runs ok in IE and Chrome but does not run in Firefox. that matter i posted as the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try change your button click from:

```
<asp:Button ID="sendButton" runat="server" OnClick="sendButton_Click" OnClientClick="return ValidatingForm()" Text="Send" />
```

to:

```
<asp:Button ID="sendButton" runat="server" OnClick="sendButton_Click" OnClientClick="return ValidatingForm" Text="Send" />
```

See same issue here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1069601.aspx?I+want+to+use+onsubmit+asp+net+wont+let+me+

Answer (score 1):

That looks more or less correct.  I would try the following:

1. Add a semicolon to your OnClientClick handler - i.e. "OnClientClick="return ValidatingForm();"
2. Put a javascript alert inside ValidatingForm (to ensure that it's actually called)
3. Check your comparison logic, maybe instead of:  document.getElementById("FnTextBox").valueOf == ""

how about trying:

```
document.getElementById("FnTextBox").value.length == 0
```